# SQLite Query Sorting

Tags: sqlite, sorting, timestamp

I'm a bit of a nub when it comes to SQL queries and I couldn't find any help so I figured I'd ask.

I'm currently working on an event tracker/calendar style thing, with two types of events.  One is a standard starts at X and ends at Y, while the other is "all day" (ie, starts at 12:01 AM, ends at 11:59 PM).  My problem is the database query to sort it properly.  What I'm trying to do is get the return such that the all-day events are at the very end of that day's list.

For example, if I have 4 events, one at 1 PM, one at 2 PM, one all day, and one tomorrow at 11 AM, it would look like:

- 1:00 PM Event
- 2:00 PM Event
- All Day Event
- Tomorrow 11:00 AM Event

I've got UNIX timestamps (in seconds for whatever reason) for start and end dates, and my current attempt is

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY all_day_flag, startTime;
```

This won't work, because it would always put the all-day events at the end, so any tips on where to refine it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want all-day events at the start or end of the list? You seem to want the former in your 2nd paragraph, but in the last paragraph you say this isn't what you want.

Comment: OK, I see. You want to distinguish by day, not just by time.

Comment: Exactly, I want it to be sorted by day, then by the all day flag, then by the time.  I'm just not sure how to get the day/date out of the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the date and time separately from your Unix timestamp, and then use the date as the first sort option, followed by all-day flag and then the time.

Try this:

```
SELECT date(startTime, 'unixepoch') AS startDate,
       time(startTime, 'unixepoch') AS startHour,
       time(endTime,   'unixepoch') AS endHour,
       all_day_flag
  FROM table
  ORDER BY
    startDate, all_day_flag, startHour;
```